# How to share IEnumerable yield return between multiple loops/subscribers?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of values that i need to perform calculations on them and i need to separate into functions each calculation logic but without running a loop for each calculation.

I mean that i need to run one and only loop and share each value between functions.

This can be done in Reactive programming using observables, but i would like to know if it's possible to be done using the current infrastructure of .NET for example using `yield return value` and `IEnumerables` or something else but without adding additional packages.

Thanks in advance.

```
void Main()
{
    var listOfValues = new List<char>
    {
        'A',
        'B',
        'C',
        'D',
        'E',
        'F',
        'G'
    };

    var lts = GetLetters(listOfValues);
    
    // I need to avoid multiple enumeration of the "listOfValues"
    // by sharing the value of the enumerator in GetLetters(...)
    CalculateSomething1(lts);
    CalculateSomething2(lts);
    
}

public string CalculateSomething1(IEnumerable<char> values)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var c in values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("runs CalculateSomething1");
        result.Append(c + "1");
    }
    return $"CalculateSomething1={result}";
}

public string CalculateSomething2(IEnumerable<char> values)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var c in values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("runs CalculateSomething2");
        
        result.Append(c + "2");
    }
    return $"CalculateSomething2={result}";
}

public IEnumerable<char> GetLetters(IEnumerable<char> values)
{
    using (var enumerator = values.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return enumerator.Current; // I want to share this value between multiple subscribers for ReadOnly.
        }
    }
}
```

Current Result:

```
runs CalculateSomething1
runs CalculateSomething1
runs CalculateSomething1
runs CalculateSomething1
runs CalculateSomething1
runs CalculateSomething1
runs CalculateSomething1
CalculateSomething1=A1B1C1D1E1F1G1
runs CalculateSomething2
runs CalculateSomething2
runs CalculateSomething2
runs CalculateSomething2
runs CalculateSomething2
runs CalculateSomething2
runs CalculateSomething2
CalculateSomething2=A2B2C2D2E2F2G2
```

What i would like to achieve:

```
runs CalculateSomething1
runs CalculateSomething2
runs CalculateSomething1
runs CalculateSomething2
runs CalculateSomething1
runs CalculateSomething2
runs CalculateSomething1
runs CalculateSomething2
runs CalculateSomething1
runs CalculateSomething2
runs CalculateSomething1
runs CalculateSomething2
runs CalculateSomething1
runs CalculateSomething2
CalculateSomething1=A1B1C1D1E1F1G1
CalculateSomething2=A2B2C2D2E2F2G2
```

Comment: `GetLetters` seems unnecessarily complicated. It is equivalent to just `return values;` (or `foreach (var value : values) yield return value;` if you want to have the loop)

Comment: @knittl thanks i'am aware of this it's part of something i was trying to do and i forgot it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this with iterators:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listOfValues = new List<char>
        {
            'A',
            'B',
            'C',
            'D',
            'E',
            'F',
            'G'
        };

        var result1 = new StringBuilder();
        var result2 = new StringBuilder();

        listOfValues.GetLetters()
            .Calculate1(result1)
            .Calculate2(result2)
            .ToArray(); //The execution is deferred until an iteration occurs, with ToArray or a foreach

        Console.WriteLine(result1);
        Console.WriteLine(result2);
    }
}

static class ProcessingPipeline
{
    public static IEnumerable<char> GetLetters(this IEnumerable<char> input)
    {
        foreach (char c in input)
        {
            yield return c;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<char> Calculate1(this IEnumerable<char> input, StringBuilder result)
    {
        foreach (char c in input)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("runs CalculateSomething1");
            result.Append(c + "1");
            yield return c;

        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<char> Calculate2(this IEnumerable<char> input, StringBuilder result)
    {
        foreach (char c in input)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("runs CalculateSomething2");
            result.Append(c + "2");
            yield return c;
        }
    }
}
```

The steps process one character at time and the result is collected with two StringBuilders passed from outside.

The output is:

```
runs CalculateSomething1
runs CalculateSomething2
runs CalculateSomething1
runs CalculateSomething2
runs CalculateSomething1
runs CalculateSomething2
runs CalculateSomething1
runs CalculateSomething2
runs CalculateSomething1
runs CalculateSomething2
runs CalculateSomething1
runs CalculateSomething2
runs CalculateSomething1
runs CalculateSomething2
A1B1C1D1E1F1G1
A2B2C2D2E2F2G2
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your methods into objects with state and move the loop out of the methods. Calling a method modifies the state which can be read in the end.

```
void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<char> letters = new List<char>
    {
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'
    };

    var calculator1 = new Calculator1();
    var calculator2 = new Calculator2();
    foreach (var letter : letters) {
      calculator1.CalculateSomething(letter);
      calculator2.CalculateSomething(letter);
    }

    var result1 = calculator1.Result;
    var result2 = calculator2.Result;
}

class Calculator1 {
  private readonly StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  public string Result =>  $"CalculateSomething1={result}";

  public void CalculateSomething(char value)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("runs CalculateSomething1");
    result.Append(c + "1");
  }
}

class Calculator2 {
  private readonly StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  public string Result => $"CalculateSomething2={result}";

  public void CalculateSomething(char value)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("runs CalculateSomething2");
    result.Append(c + "2");
  }
}
```

An alternative could be managing the "result state" (your `StringBuilder`) outside of the methods. But this decouples behavior and state and is easy to get wrong, especially when extending.

```
void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<char> letters = new List<char>
    {
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'
    };

    var result1 = new StringBuilder();
    var result2 = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var letter : letters) {
      CalculateSomething1(result1, letter);
      CalculateSomething2(result2, letter);
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"CalculateSomething1={result1}");
    Console.WriteLine($"CalculateSomething2={result2}");
}

public void CalculateSomething1(StringBuilder result, char value)
{
    Console.WriteLine("runs CalculateSomething1");
    result.Append(c + "1");
}

public void CalculateSomething2(StringBuilder result, char value)
{
    Console.WriteLine("runs CalculateSomething2");
    result.Append(c + "2");
}
```